# Entity Framework 6 Code First UDT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am struggling to determine how to define a User Defined Type using EF6. I understand that it's possible using Complex Types but have found very little other information on how to do this.

Suppose this example where we are inserting multiple rows into the User table and one row in the the team table. The schema of the UDT mirrors the table it is being inserted into.

```
const string insertQuery = @"
BEGIN TRY
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Team] (Id, TeamName) 
        VALUES (, );

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[User] (Id, Name)
        SELECT * FROM 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH";

DataTable userTable = new DataTable();
userTableType.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long));
userTableType.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
userTableType.Rows.Add(1, "Mike");
userTableType.Rows.Add(2, "Sam");

object values = new {
    TeamId = 10,
    TeamName = "something",
    // dapper extension method
    Users = userTable.AsTableValuedParameter("[dbo].[UserTableType]");
};

// wrapper around dapper. not important.
await this.sqlAccess.ExecuteAsync(InsertQuery, values);
```

This query runs as expected if I have previously ran in SSMS (or I'm assuming any query that doesn't reference the created type)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'UsersTableType')
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserTableType] AS TABLE (Id bigint, Name nvarchar(max));
```

I need to make sure this type is available when the database is created which is hopefully achieved using a code first migration or even code manually written in the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this other than using `MigrationBuilder.Sql()`.  I would create an empty migration then add something like the following to the `Up` and `Down` methods:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    const String sql = "CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserTableType] AS TABLE (Id bigint, Name nvarchar(max))";
    migrationBuilder.Sql(sql);
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"DROP TYPE IF EXISTS [UserTableType]");
}
```